# How do I get chrome working with selenium, using php webdriver?

Tags: php, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Everything works fine with Firefox, but I can't start chrome. I'm on linux, using php webdriver bindings.

```
require_once "/usr/local/src/selenium/php-webdriver-bindings-0.9.0/phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";
putenv("PATH=".getenv("PATH").':'.'/usr/local/src/selenium/chrome_webdriver/'); //Prepare for chrome

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
//$webdriver->connect("chrome");
$webdriver->connect("chrome","",array(
    'webdriver.chrome.driver'=>'/usr/local/src/selenium/chrome_webdriver/chromedriver',
    ));
```

The error message I get is "*The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property*". As you can see, I've tried setting that in the desiredCapabilities array, but that must be the wrong place. I can see in the selenium logs that my setting is getting through as this log line shows:

```
INFO - Executing: [new session: {javascriptEnabled=true, webdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/src/selenium/chrom..., browserName=chrome, nativeEvents=false, version=}] at URL: /session)
```

I start selenium with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar`

I'm using Chromium v.18.

I created a shortcut /usr/bin/google-chrome that points to /usr/bin/chromium-browser

I can start chromedriver manually with no problems. It says:

```
port=9515
version=20.0.1133.0
```

Having that running, or not, does not make any difference to the error message selenium gives me.

UPDATE: Related question: [selenium 2 chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450416/selenium-2-chrome-driver) (answer there is for java, not php)

Comment: Can you try passing the webdriver.chrome.driver value while starting the server? Like java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver = pathtochromedriver -jar selenium-server.jar

Comment: @A.J Yes! Could you move your answer to an answer so I can mark it correct, please.

Comment: You're using the code for Java. It is not supported in PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try passing the webdriver.chrome.driver property from commandline while starting the selenium server. Like this:

```
 java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver = pathtochromedriver -jar selenium-server.jar
```

I am not sure about the reason why the other one is not working. You need to check whether its **really** setting the system property from code..

Comment: Thanks, confirmed that this works. I guess that _system properties_ and webdriver _desiredCapabilities_ are different things.

Comment: The `-Dwebdriver...` lines must be set **before** `selenium-server.jar` is called, otherwise it will not open a Chrome browser and instead open Firefox by default (at least, mine was).

Comment: Im facing the Could not find the load main clas error  when i hit above mentioned command in my command line .

Answer (score 3):

Without any blanks it worked for me on WinXP32:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server.jar
```