# How can I get HTML data from a site who use CloudFlare?

Tags: php, curl

First at all, sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to get the HTML code from https://www.uasd.edu.do/ but when I try to catch the code with the PHP function "file_get_contents()" or using cURL, it just simply doesn't work.

With "file_get_contents()" it returns with a 403 HTTP error. With cURL, it returns with a fictional captcha that just do not appear.

I tried sending Cookies with cURL, setting a user-agent, but I'm still on the same point. Also I tried to find the real IP address of the site, but with not success. Please help me! I'll really appreciate that.

The code:

```
    $curl = curl_init(); 

    if (!$curl) {
        die("Is not working"); 
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://uasd.edu.do/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    $html = curl_exec($curl); 

    echo $html;
    curl_close($curl);
```

The output:

> Please enable cookies. One more step Please complete the security
>   check to access www.uasd.edu.do Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?
>
> Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary
>   access to the web property. What can I do to prevent this in the
>   future?
>
> If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an
>   anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with
>   malware.
>
> If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network
>   administrator to run a scan across the network looking for
>   misconfigured or infected devices.
>
> Cloudflare Ray ID: 4fcbf50d18679f88 • Your IP: ***.***.***.*** •
>   Performance & security by Cloudflare

**Note: The *"please enable cookies"* appear using and not using cookies.**

Comment: Can you share the code??

Comment: @salmanfaris Sure. I already added it.

Comment: What is the output of the code??

Comment: @salmanfaris Done!

Comment: @OmarUreña It is throwing captcha. You may need to use web driver. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792403/how-do-i-get-chrome-working-with-selenium-using-php-webdriver) to know how.