# Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome using selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating webdriver as follows:

```
var driver = require("selenium-webdriver");
driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer(server.address()).
    withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).
    build();

it('should append query to title', function() {
        driver.get('http://www.google.com');
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
        driver.wait(function() {
            return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                return 'webdriver - Google Search' === title;
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

This works fine on firefox. With chrome, it gives me the following exception after opening the chrome instance: Could anyone please let me know how to solve this issue? Also, the chrome Version 26.0.1410.65 which is the latest.

I have latest version of `chromedriver` installed on my machine.

```
 UnknownError: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 28.32 seconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.3', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromedriver version should be the latest. Once, I updated the chromedriver, the issue is fixed. I updated chromedriver on Mac using homebrew as follows:
brew update;
brew upgrade chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have chrome driver bin setup. See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450416/selenium-2-chrome-driver/)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\pathto\my\chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh. Seems like I didn't have updated version of chromedriver on my machine. Once, I updated the version, the issue is fixed.