# How to get the path for .exe file which resides in src/main/resources

Tags: java, maven

I am doing automation for one of our project, for that I coded like the below:

```
public void m() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver.exe").getFile());
        System.out.println("123");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

It's working when I execute in eclipse. but when I am testing with the maven generated jar, it is giving an exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: `C:\Users\rkowsu\Desktop\jar\file:\C:\Users\UU1\Desktop\jar\resources-part-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\chromedriver.exe`

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work with chrome driver in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867102/how-to-work-with-chrome-driver-in-maven)

Comment: I gone through with the above link example, they mentioned the chromedriver.exe path as system path, If I do the same, it'll work. But whereas my requirement is bit different. I placed the .exe file under src/main/resources and I am getting the .exe path with the java code as I mentioned.

Comment: Can you post your POM.xml?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am facing the same problem, I have a JAR with chrome driver within an executable, and I cannot get it to launch, it doesn't find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `System.setProperty()` you should be providing it with `"webdriver.chrome.driver"` and the `relative\path\to\exe`. If your project structure looks like this:

```
src
    main
          java
             App.java
          resources
             chromedriver.exe
```

You should use `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator +"chromedriver.exe")`

This should be able to find the .exe whether or not you run from a jar or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joe, It'll works in windows eclipse with the personal machine. But when we push this code into the environment as a jar, it didn't work. As @Steve mentioned .exe file doesn't executes/do it's job in the jar as it's zipped in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have chromedriver.exe in the `src/main/resources` directory of your application then it will get packaged up into your jar file.

It can't be executed from there.

Have a look at the answer to [How to work with chrome driver in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867102/how-to-work-with-chrome-driver-in-maven).

Comment: Yes. you're right, the .exe file packed into the jar. so the .exe file path always be pointed to windows explorer but not in to the jar right?