# Maven can't connect to remote standalone Selenium server

Tags: java, maven, google-chrome, selenium

I am working on creating a test suite for a project at work, where we will be testing our application on several operating systems from a central box (all vms). The box with the tests on is a CentOS server utilizing `apache-maven` for the tests. I am trying to test against a Windows 10 box running `selenium-standalone-server` but have had no luck so far. Here is the configuration for each box:

#### CentOS

- Apache Maven
- IP address - 192.168.4.62
- Subnet mask - 255.255.255.0

**Sample Test**

```
package com.netsweeper.browsertests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.net.URL;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class ReadyTest {
    @Test
    public void accessChrome() {
       try {
            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.60:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
            driver.get("http://google.com");
            assertEquals("The page title should equal Google at the start of the test", "Google", driver.getTitle());
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
        catch ( java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Broken");
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Output**

```
[root@62 browser_tests]# mvn -Dtest=ReadyTest test

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Browser Tests 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ browsertests ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /src/client_filter/browser_tests/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ browsertests ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ browsertests ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /src/client_filter/browser_tests/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ browsertests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ browsertests ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /src/client_filter/browser_tests/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.netsweeper.browsertests.ReadyTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.392 sec <<< FAILURE!
accessChrome(com.netsweeper.browsertests.ReadyTest)  Time elapsed: 1.325 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 732 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: '62.4.168.192.in-addr.arpa.support', ip: '192.168.4.62', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
        at com.netsweeper.browsertests.ReadyTest.accessChrome(ReadyTest.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Results :

Tests in error:
  accessChrome(com.netsweeper.browsertests.ReadyTest): The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html(..)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.391 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-16T11:17:21-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/168M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project browsertests: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /src/client_filter/browser_tests/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

[root@62 browser_tests]#
```

#### Windows 10

- Selenium Standalone Server

  - Placed in `C:\Users\------\Documents\client_filter\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0`
  - Started with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0` from said directory
  - Correctly starts running
- Chrome Driver

  - Downloaded and placed in `C:\Windows\System32`
  - Starting it from command line works correctly, so it is in $PATH
  - `C:\Users\Kendall Roth\Documents\client_filter> chromedriver.exe`
- IP address - 192.168.4.60
- Netmask - 255.255.255.0

However, the error above seems to indicate that the chromedriver is not in the right place to be found, even though it can be found from anywhere (due to being in path). The error was also displayed in the Windows console, and said the same thing.

I have looked around, but can't find anything that deals with a remote install of the Selenium standalone server. This link unfortunately did not work, but was similar to my issue (albeit on a local scale): 
[selenium-2-chrome-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450416/selenium-2-chrome-driver)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was a rather simple fix. Although `C:\Windows\` is not in the system path this was where the `chromedriver.exe` was supposed to go. Placing it here instead of in `C:\Windows\System32\` appears to solve the problem. I'm not sure if this is a remote server only thing or if it extends to local standalone instances as well, but this solution worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that including the chromedriver.exe in the resources folder within the project to be a workable fail-safe so I don't have to rely on a new user or remote server having the executable in the right location within their file system.