# Use WebDriverManager with jasmine-maven-plugin to use Chrome Headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, jasmine-maven-plugin, webdrivermanager-java

I have a Maven project configured with jasmine-maven-plugin to run javascript tests. I'd like to switch from Phantomjs to Chrome headless without downloading and setting the driver's path executable.
I've found WebDriverManager could help, but it seems the download could be started programmatically in a class with:

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

I've configured the pom.xml to use the driver ([as explained here](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin/pull/325)), now is it possible to configure the pom.xml to also use WebDriverManager to handle the ChromeDriver download without configuring the webdriver.chrome.driver property?

I even thought to use a different jasmine's spec runner template, but it seems it can be just a simple [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/index.html) string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed WebDriverManager works only in runtime. If you want to export the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property directly in Maven, you can use the [selenium-standalone-server-plugin](https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin) Maven plugin, or directly export the value of that variable within your plugin (you can find something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450416/selenium-2-chrome-driver)).